# show/hide dropdown on clicking respective checkboxes

Tags: javascript

**Requirement:** On checking/unchecking 1st checkbox, I need to show/hide 1st dropdown, similarly on checking/unchecking 2nd checkbox, I need to show/hide 2nd dropdown.

Please note that since these values of checkboxes comes from DB, and I iterate over them to show on front-end.. I can only have a common `showMe()` function for all checkboxes

**Issue:** I am not able to get this work when the checkbox1 is unchecked or checking checkbox2 using the logic I have written. Can someone suggest a better succinct way of doing it?

```js
function showMe (box, box1) {
        
        var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("c1");
        var vis = "none";
        var checkedOne;
        for(var i=0;i<chboxs.length;i++) { 
            if(chboxs[i].checked){
              checkedOne = i;
              alert(checkedOne);
             vis = "block";
                break;
            }
        }
        document.getElementsByName(box)[checkedOne].style.display = vis;
    }
```

```html
    <input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="showMe('catsndogs','parrot')">Checkbox1
    <input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="showMe('catsndogs','parrot')">Checkbox2
     <select name="catsndogs" style="display:none">
     <option>Select</option>
 <optgroup label="Cats">
  <option>Tiger</option>
  <option>Leopard</option>
  <option>Lynx</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Dogs">
  <option>Grey Wolf</option>
  <option>Red Fox</option>
  <option>Fennec</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>


    <select name="parrot" style="display:none">
    <option>Select1</option>
 <optgroup label="Bird">
  <option>Tiger</option>
  <option>Leopard</option>
  <option>Lynx</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want it to do?

```js
function showMe (box, box1) {
  var chkboxes = document.getElementsByName('c1');
  var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select')
  var bools = []
  for (var i = 0; i < chkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (chkboxes[i].checked) {
      selects[i].style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      selects[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

  
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="showMe('catsndogs','parrot')">Checkbox1
    <input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="showMe('catsndogs','parrot')">Checkbox2
     <select name="catsndogs" style="display:none">
     <option>Select</option>
 <optgroup label="Cats">
  <option>Tiger</option>
  <option>Leopard</option>
  <option>Lynx</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Dogs">
  <option>Grey Wolf</option>
  <option>Red Fox</option>
  <option>Fennec</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>


    <select name="parrot" style="display:none">
    <option>Select1</option>
 <optgroup label="Bird">
  <option>Tiger</option>
  <option>Leopard</option>
  <option>Lynx</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure js approach; associate each checkbox with a dropdown and toggle display accordingly.

```js
window.onload = () =>  loadFunctions();

loadFunctions = () => {
   document.getElementById('check1').onclick = () =>   toggle('drop1','blockDis');
   document.getElementById('check2').onclick = () =>   toggle('drop2','blockDis');
}


toggle = (divId,className) => {
   let isPresent = document.getElementById(divId).classList.contains(className);
   if(!isPresent) document.getElementById(divId).classList += className;
   else document.getElementById(divId).classList -= className;
}
```

```css
select {
  display:none;
}
.blockDis {
  display : block;
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox'/ id="check1"> Box 1
<input type='checkbox'/id="check2"> Box 2
<select id="drop1">
<option>Dropdown 1</option>
</select>
<select id="drop2">
<option>Dropdown 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```js
function showMe (elem, box)
{
  if(elem.checked)
  {
     vis = "block";
  }
  else
  {
      vis="none";
  }
  document.getElementsByName(box)[0].style.display = vis;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="showMe(this, 'catsndogs')">Checkbox1
<input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="showMe(this, 'parrot')">Checkbox2
<select name="catsndogs" style="display:none">
<option>Select</option>
 <optgroup label="Cats">
  <option>Tiger</option>
  <option>Leopard</option>
  <option>Lynx</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Dogs">
  <option>Grey Wolf</option>
  <option>Red Fox</option>
  <option>Fennec</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>


<select name="parrot" style="display:none">
<option>Select1</option>
 <optgroup label="Bird">
  <option>Tiger</option>
  <option>Leopard</option>
  <option>Lynx</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showMe (selectName) {
    var select = document.querySelector("select[name='" + selectName + "']"); 
    
    if(event.target.checked){
      select.classList.add('show');
    }
    else{
     select.classList.remove('show');
    }    
}
```

```css
select{
 display:none;
}

.show{
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="showMe('catsndogs')">Checkbox1
<input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="showMe('parrot')">Checkbox2

<select name="catsndogs">
  <option>Select</option>
 <optgroup label="Cats">
  <option>Tiger</option>
  <option>Leopard</option>
  <option>Lynx</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Dogs">
  <option>Grey Wolf</option>
  <option>Red Fox</option>
  <option>Fennec</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>


<select name="parrot">
  <option>Select1</option>
 <optgroup label="Bird">
  <option>Tiger</option>
  <option>Leopard</option>
  <option>Lynx</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```